# Do firebase functions run on phonegap desktop?

Tags: sqlite, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, phonegap

I am currently trying to build an app that requires users to login and save certain data to a database. I am developing using phonegap but I am fairly new to development. How would I go about using a firebase database to store and read data that users store [Its all text data for small fields, a business card storage app]? Is there any documentation that can help? Most documentation I find points to ionic and firebase, would that be better to use for development?

Would also like to know if the phonegap desktop app for prototyping can be used when prototyping firebase code.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there shouldn't be a problem using Firebase with Phonegap cordova Project, including statistics and database. according to this:
https://phonegap.com/blog/2013/04/16/firebase-phonegap-integration/